# drawing point on canvas not working on safari

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, safari

I would like to use canvas to draw points on mouseover: my implementation works fine on chrome and firefox, but for some reason it doesn't work on safari (however, drawing a line on mouseover works on safari)

any help would be appreciated!

---> https://draw-9.superhi.com/

code:

```
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");

let x = 0;
let y = 0;


let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.strokeStyle = "black";
context.lineWidth = 15;
context.lineCap = "round";

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  
    x = e.offsetX;
    y = e.offsetY;

  context.moveTo(x, y);
   context.lineTo(x, y);
    context.stroke();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In accordance with [the specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#trace-a-path), Safari does

> 2. Prune all zero-length [line segments](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#line-segments) from *path*.
> 3. Remove from *path* any subpaths containing no lines (i.e. subpaths with just one point).

before tracing it.

Your path is made entirely of such zero-length line segments (`moveTo(x,y); lineTo(x,y)`), and hence nothing is left to be drawn.

Other browsers are buggy here: [Firefox bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=691187), [Chrome's](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=644067&q=zero-length%20line%20segments&can=2), but a [specs issue is currently open](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/1079) to discuss which behavior should be the default one. Also, Chrome recently changed their behavior, but it doesn't add much interop...

So in order to do what you want, i.e draw a circle, use the `arc()` method. Also, don't forget to call `beginPath()` otherwise your path will just grow and you'll end up stroking at the same place over and over leading to bad graphics and performances.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");

let x = 0;
let y = 0;

const radius = 7.5;
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.strokeStyle = "black";

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  
  x = e.offsetX;
  y = e.offsetY;

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(x + radius, y);
  context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
  context.fill();

});
```

```html
<canvas width="900" height="900">
```